# Can I upgrade parent VM and have all linked clones updated too?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I want to create a base OS image and lots of child linked clone images that share the parent's disk. This way I'm not duplicating the base OS 10 times. I want to update the parent OS and have that automatically reflected in all the child OSes.

Right now I'm using VMware Fusion w/ Ubuntu and Windows. In both cases I have to update the child images individually. After a while all the images become bloated because they have individual copies of the same OS updates.

Is there any VM and OS combination that can support this scenario?